# GitHub inquiry concerning branch updating

Tags: git, github

We use GitHub at work. I created a branch and made some changes to resolve an issue. It was clear once I started testing that the changes did not work. Instead of backing out the changes, I deleted the branch (local and remote) and created a new branch with the same name. The new changes worked and I merged my branch with our main branch.
When testing was done against the main branched with the merged changes, the changes in the deleted branch were reintroduced, along with my new changes.
It almost looked like, because I used the same name on the new branch as the old branch, when Git did the branch merge, it used all branches, deleted or not. I am sure, that had I used a different name for the new branch, this would not have happened.

Has this ever happened to anyone else?

Comment: when you created the branch, was it a branch directly off of master?

Comment: Can you reproduce this carefully?

Comment: I tried to duplicate the error and, sadly, I cannot. It may not be GitHub but I do know that I remove the bad code, committed the change, deleted the branch and created the branch with the same name. I thought I may have missed one or two places where the code was not deleted but all of the code had returned.

Comment: It may not have been GitHub but I wanted to inquire and see if anyone else encountered this or something similar to this. If there are no others, I'm going to close the question and move  on.

Comment: And thank you for replying.

Comment: Noam, I created it from the master branch